# How to use enum in select component of Form in antd for form validation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, antd, ant-design-pro

I am using antd Form and there I have a select-options field. Select field will show 6 options but only 3 options can be selected. If user select any other option which is not from the enum list, that select should be highlighted as an error field.

So suppose I have an enum list with ["January", "February", "March"] and select field has first 6 months from January to June. If user select May or June it should show an error.
Is antd supports something like that?

Comment: we can do it by custom . can you please share some code of select so can help u out .

Comment: Vyas, can you help with something like this? (sorry for bad format, comment won't let me format it will.)  export enum contactSortOptions //define options for sorting contacts here
{
    Name = "Name",
    Address = "Address",
    Updated = "Updated"
}   <Form.Item label="Sort By">
                            <Select defaultValue="Updated" onChange={this.props.reportStore?.ContactListStore.ChangeTerritorySort} options={contactSortOptions.Address}>               
                            </Select>
                        </Form.Item>